# OpenSSL Unable to add certificates to database

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to setup a test lab where I can use certificates for authentication. I'm using debian squeeze, glasfish and openssl.

After I have made a client certificate and try to store it in the database I get an error:

`1 out of 1 certificate request certified, commit? [y/n]y`

`write out database with 1 new entries`

`unable to rename ./demoCA/index.txt to ./demoCA/index.txt.old`

`reason: is a directory`

When I made the self-signed CA certificate it worked fine, but now it won't work. Maby I'm missing the obvious since I can't find anything about it on the internet. So any guidance in solving this would be much appreciated.

Best regards
Mari

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the file `./demoCA/index.txt`. Can you run ls -al on `./demoCA/`?

Comment: Yes, it shows all the files in demoCA

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: Is there anything particular I'm looking for?

Comment: total 44
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3 Feb 27 12:39 crlnumber
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   52 Feb 27 14:30 index.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   21 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.attr
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   20 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.attr.new
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  110 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.new
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 12:38 index.txt.old
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:30 newcerts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3 Feb 27 16:30 serial
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3 Feb 27 16:16 serial.old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of your `ls -al`

```
total 44 drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:30 . 
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:25 .. 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3 Feb 27 12:39 crlnumber 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 52 Feb 27 14:30 index.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 21 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.attr 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.attr.new 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 110 Feb 27 16:30 index.txt.new 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 12:38 index.txt.old 
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 27 16:30 newcerts 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3 Feb 27 16:30 serial -rw-r--r-- 
1 root root 3 Feb 27 16:16 serial.old
```

`index.txt.old` is in fact a directory. You can tell because of the `d` in `drwxr-xr-x`. I don't know about everything you are using, but you can try backing this up `mv index.txt.old index.txt.old.backup` and then it should run correctly.

Comment: Get the message: mv: cannot stat `index.txt.old` : no such file or directoty. But since I now know what the problem might be I'll google some more and see if I an cfind a solution. Thanks for all the help

Comment: I fixed the problem by deleteing index.txt.old `rm -rf index.txt.old`. And then created the certificat again. Now the database got updated.

Comment: Excellent! Make sure to mark answers as solutions if it fixes your problem.